# super() method in Java

Tags: java, methods, constructor, super

```
class Animal {
    Animal(){
        super();
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    Bird(String name){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    
    Bird(){
        System.out.println("Unknown");
    }
}
public class WhizSuperKeyWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bird("Parrot");

    }

}
```

Hi, this is my first post. I am learning Core Java. Can you please help me understand what's the use of super() method in parent class. I understand super() is used in Child class to invoke constructor of Parent class. I am puzzled what is super() method doing in Parent class. this() is used in Parent class to invoke constructor of current class.
Many thanks.

Comment: In your base class constructor `super()` is unnecessary. You can omit it. Perhaps someone included it because they are in the habit of *always* calling a super-constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It is pointless. All objects in Java inherit from the `Object` class. Java automatically inserts an implicit `super()` call in constructors of classes with no explicit superclass, so the call to `super()` in `Animal` is pointless.

Comment: I've actually never seen my IDE (neither Eclipse nor IntelliJ) adding a call to `super()` when I create a constructor for a class which does not `extends`. With "Java automatically inserts", do you mean it does that in bytecode?

Comment: Yes, it will be present in the bytecode